# spectral gap of the graph / Markov chain

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. The gradient of a function $f:V\longrightarrow R$ is defined on the edges of the graph, given by the discrete derivative
$$
\nabla f(e)=f(y)-f(x), \quad e=(x,y) \in E
$$

Take $V=S_{2n}$ the group of permutations $\pi$ of the set $\{1, \ldots 2n\}$ and $e=(\pi, \pi \tau) \in E$ for any transposition $\tau$.

I am trying to find a lower bound of the spectral gap of the graph $(S_{2n}, E)$.
I guess it should be well-known.
Any literature would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Does "some transposition" mean "some given transposition" or "any transposition"?

Comment: @joriki: Thank you. For any transposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Papers by Persi Diaconis and co-authors in general, and in particular [Comparison Techniques for Random Walk on Finite Groups](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-21/issue-4/Comparison-Techniques-for-Random-Walk-on-Finite-Groups/10.1214/aop/1176989013.full), Persi Diaconis and Laurent Saloff-Coste, Ann. Probab. Volume 21, Number 4 (1993), 2131-2156.